# Meaning of "See more of"

Tags: meaning

I wanted to ask what is the meaning of "see more of", or does it have few meanings?

I've read that "see more of someone" equals "see someone more often", but I've also seen the phrase being used in other examples, like in this(http://czy.li/Zj12F) page of a Spider-Man comic.

Also you can quite often hear "See more of their adventures next monday" or something like this, and it doesn't fit with "see someone more often" definition, I mean it wouldn't even make sense "See one of those spider-man more often this summer" or "See their adventures more often next monday".

So "See more of" can be used in few different meanings or something? Could someone please explain it to me? Thanks

Comment: Hello, Adrian. Welcome to ELU. You are _strongly_ encouraged to show a reasonable amount of research you yourself have done to accompany a question here. (Though posters needn't wear a tie any more.)

Comment: See, for instance [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/more) (sense 3a) for the 'see more of X' = 'see X more often' sense. Obviously, 'You can see more of the mountain from this hotel' is not that sense.

Comment: First of all-Thank you for answering.
I would also like to ask about that spider-man panel. "See more of one of those spider-men this summer" fits more with the second sense for me, since "See one of those spider-men more often this summer" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Here, an intermediate reading is a deleted form of 'See more adventures of one ...'. Comics and some newspapers don't worry overmuch about precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**More of** means quite simply **in a greater quantity than already experienced**. That experience can be anything - time, area, episodes in a series etc.

> **Boy to girl:**
>  "I've really enjoyed our first evening together, I'd
>   like to see more of you." = I'd like to see you more often.
>  **TV voice-over**:
>  "That's the end the first episode, see
>   more of their adventures next Monday" = you can enjoy more episodes every Monday.
>  **Estate agent to customer**:
>   "Well you've seen the kitchen, would you like to see more of the
>   house?" = You can't judge a house on just the kitchen, you need to see more rooms.
>   **Interviewer to job applicant**:
>   "I'm very interested in your portfolio so far, can I see some more of your work?" = I need to see other things you have produced before I employ you?

Comment: By "you can enjoy more episodes every Monday" you mean "you can enjoy new episode every Monday"?
(I'm still learning english)

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

"I'd LIKE to see MORE of you."  (I'd like to see you more often.)

"I'd like to SEE MORE of you."  (That dress is a bit Amish, for my taste.)

"I'd like to see more of YOU."  (This work of yours is very derivative - it doesn't

illustrate your unique talent/viewpoint/sensibility.)

"I'd like to SEE more of the city." (I want to go to the tourist attractions.)

"I'd like to see MORE of the city." (I want to go where the "locals" go.)

"I'd like to see more of THE CITY." (I want to go to the seedy/dodgy area, and gawk at

the fringe of society.)